# Boost Program Options dependent options

Tags: c++, boost, command-line-arguments, boost-program-options

Is there any way of making program options dependent on other options using `boost::program_options`?

For example, my program can accept the following sample arguments:

```
wifi --scan --interface=en0
wifi --scan --interface=en0 --ssid=network
wifi --do_something_else
```

In this example, the `interface` and `ssid` arguments are only valid if they are accompanied by `scan`. They are dependent on the `scan` argument.

Is there any way to enforce this automatically with `boost::program_options`? It can of course be implemented manually but it seems like there must be a better way.

Comment: I suspect there is no way of telling boost::po to do that: take a look at the public APIs for [value_semantic](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/doc/html/boost/program_options/value_semantic.html) (the `po::value<stuff>()` bit) and [option_description](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/doc/html/boost/program_options/option_description.html)

Answer (score 7):

You can define two dependent options simply defining a small function as explained in [real.cpp](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/program_options/example/real.cpp). For example, you can specify two depending (or conflicting) options defining a `option_dependency()` function:

```
void option_dependency(const boost::program_options::variables_map & vm,
    const std::string & for_what, const std::string & required_option)
{
  if (vm.count(for_what) && !vm[for_what].defaulted())
    if (vm.count(required_option) == 0 || vm[required_option].defaulted())
      throw std::logic_error(std::string("Option '") + for_what 
          + "' requires option '" + required_option + "'.");
}
```

and then calling

```
option_dependency (vm, "interface", "scan");
option_dependency (vm, "ssid", "scan");
```

right after `boost::program_options::store()`

Pay attention that this function `option_dependency` is one-way only. In this case `ssid` requires `scan` option, but not the other way around.